# RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE return while sending sms using Sms Manager in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am using Sms Manager to sent sms to multiple users but i am getting RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE (Generic failure) .how to resolve this issue?

```
// ---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

Here i am using SmsManager and sendSms() taken number and message as parameters.

Comment: post your logcat and relevant code.

Comment: i added source above @Shayanpourvatan

Comment: Are you getting this error on a phone, or in the emulator? GENERIC_FAILURE is usually related to some internal radio problem

Comment: did you test on real phone or on emulator you get this error?

Comment: I TESTED IN MOBILE @Shayanpourvatan

Comment: i really don't know why this happened for you, because i wrote one application and use this code too, but all things is ok, only thing that i say is , Are You Sure Get RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE? did you can send sms via other application?

Comment: I too had the same issue..Actually I had given only 9 digits in the phone number.. That was the issue...Check your phone number

Comment: i'm getting SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE on marshmallow devices only. i had checked on other devices and it's work fine.

Answer (score 2):

May be you should shorten your SMS body to fit in only 1 sms (which is only 160 charachters), I used the same code & got the exact same error & when I shortened the sms under 160, it was sent successfully :)

Comment: problem is people do want to send 160+ character messages

Answer (score 0):

If your Message body contains more then 160 characters, you need to send SMS as multi-part.

Answer (score 0):

In case the SMS is too long, you can split it and send it as parts:

```
            val messageToSend = ...
            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
            val parts = smsManager.divideMessage(messageToSend)
            for (number in smsNumbersToSend)
                smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, null, null)
```